# Access domain class of main project inside custom plugin project

Tags: grails

I am working on a project which is further subdivided into plugin projects. So I include all plugins inside Main project and it works.

Now there are few domain classes like User which are inside Main project. I am trying to access it inside my custom plugin project.

Note: I am not trying to access Plugin's domain class inside main project but reverse of it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to reference application classes in a plugin. If you think about it because a plugin should be an independent functionality, that can be plugged in any application.

Comment: To be more specific about this answer, while accessing a main application's domain classes is not really possible from a plugin, you can restructure your application so that the domain classes of the main application themselves are in a plugin, say "app-core", and then make other plugins depend on it. This is less crazy than it seems, and I found that it basically is just shuffling files around even for a large existing app. Reference http://www.bobbywarner.com/2011/06/21/grails-setup/